# Displaying the process of a randomize number generator with threading sleep

Tags: c#

I am sorry I am a newbie at this, I just need to know how do you display the process of the randomize generator by using:

- `Application.DoEvents();`
- `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep();`

For example,

```
Random DiceNumber = new Random();
int Dice1Value = DiceNumber.Next(1, 7);
```

I want to see the process of random generator until it stops at the number
like,
2,
5,
3,
4,
then finally the number generator chooses 6.

Comment: 1) Do not use `Application.DoEvents()`. 2) Use a `while` loop with `Thread.Sleep()` if you're in a console app or with `Task.Delay()` if you're creating an application with a UI thread so you don't block it.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming your are in some UI with a message pump or dispatcher, most likely *WinForms* as you mentioned `DoEvents`.

Instead of `DoEvents` and `Sleep`, you can use a more modern approach with *Tasks* and the *async and await pattern*

```
private Random _rand = new Random();
private bool _stop;

private async void Button1_StartClick(...)
{
    _stop = false;

    while(!_stop)
    {
        label1.Text = _rand.Next(1, 7);
        await Task.Delay(500);
    }
}

private void Button1_StopClick(...)
  => _stop = true;
```

<sub>***Note 1*** : You **will** need to hook up the appropriate events to the appropriate buttosn</sub>

<sub>***Note 2*** : Untested. I am not responsible for the people you maim or otherwise injure with this code. But it should give you an idea</sub>